# Contacts with Multiple Accounts /Multiple Email addresses

Tags: account, contact, relationships, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

I have a user requirement where a contact may need to be associated to multiple Accounts and store multiple email addresses based on the Accounts they are working for.

For Example, Joe Blogs who works as a contractor starts work with Company A, then works with Company B, and then works with Company C. Joe has multiple email addresses for each different account - joe@companyA.com, joe@companyB.com and joe@companyC.com.

I am using the new SF Feature, Contacts with Multiple /Related Accounts which is great, but I need a way to store multiple emails for the contacts based on the company that they are with.

Also, I would like to be able to integrate Salesforce for Outlook, so that when a Sales person can send an email to any email address that joe has (joe@companyA.com, joe@companyB.com etc.) and the email will be mapped to Joe's contact record in Salesforce. (Ideally, I would like to have one Contact record for Joe in Salesforce). Any ideas, either using the new feature or without using the new feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom email field on the Account Contact Relationship, that way you'll have a unique email for that specific relationship. Go to:

Setup>Accounts>Account Contact Relationships>Fields

and create a new field